# "Column reference ambiguous or duplicate names" on Apache Phoenix when using alias

Tags: sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

Using Apache Phoenix 4.6.0 against HBase 1.1.2.

I have a simple table created like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "events" (
"uuid" VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
"event"."session" VARCHAR(64),
"event"."name" VARCHAR(32),
"event"."date" UNSIGNED_DATE,
"product"."name" VARCHAR(32),
"data"."*" VARCHAR(64)
) default_column_family='event', IMMUTABLE_ROWS=true
```

These queries works:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" AS search WHERE search."event"."name" = 'search'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT click."event"."session" 
FROM "events" AS click WHERE "event"."name" = 'click')
```

But this one not:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" AS search 
WHERE search."event"."name" = 'search' 
AND search."event"."session" NOT IN (SELECT click."event"."session" 
FROM "events" AS click 
WHERE click."event"."name" = 'click');
```

> Error: ERROR 502 (42702): Column reference ambiguous or duplicate
>   names. columnName=name SQLState:  42702 ErrorCode: 502

Why?

Comment: to get your answer you have to first send email dev-subscribe@phoenix.apache.org to subscribe to their emailing list and once you are confirmed in that emailing group then send email to dev@phoenix.apache.org.

Answer (score 0):

Try `count(1)` on the one that doesn't work. You're clearly aliasing the tables, but maybe something is going on in the background with the asterisk that is not using the aliases.